# Checking for special characters and spaces

Tags: java, special-characters

I have a hangman game created in java. I want to create a simple function that will check if the word input has white space and/or special characters.

I've found the functions String.replaceAll(), but I haven't been able to dig up a premade function that returns a boolean value for if there are special charactors and/or white space.

Is there a function out there already? Or at least a simpler way of specifying no white space or special characters other than doing the following?

```
public  void checkWord()
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(wordArray[i] == '1' || wordArray[i] == '2' || wordArray[i] == '3' || wordArray[i] == '4' || wordArray[i] == '5' || wordArray[i] == '6' || wordArray[i] == '7' || wordArray[i] == '8' || wordArray[i] == '9'  )
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid characters used in the word");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

The function is getting dense, and I've only covered digits. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
public boolean isValidWord(String w) {
    return w.matches("[A-Za-z]*");
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
[A-Za-z] - capital or lowercase letter
*        - zero or more
```

More info on regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: This is perfect! Working already. The only case that I haven't gotten to work after this edit is when there is a literal " " (space) in the entry. I really don't want to have to deal with a user trying to use a phrase in the hangman game. Thoughts? I tried just adding on a case of `|| w[i] == ' '` but it did not work. I have the string in a char array as well for this purpose.

Comment: @ZAX `isValidWord(new String(charArrray))`